# How to create two divs with same height, one of them with vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have this layout, using only css:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="base-height">
    <pre>
      some
      items
      with dynamic height
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div id="with-scroll">
    some other content with vertical scroll, if it is higher than div#base-height
  </div>
</div>
```

`div#container` should have the same height as `div#base-height`. `div#base-height` and `div#with-scroll` should be displayed side by side. If `div#with-scroll` is higher than `div#base-height`, it should have vertical scroll.

Comment: Please post what have you tried

Comment: Position `.container` relative, and then position `#with-scroll` absolute, with top and bottom set to 0. Then `#base-height` alone will determine the height of the container, and `#with-scroll` will get its height _from_ the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="base-height" class = "same-height">
    <pre>
      some
      items
      with dynamic height
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div id="with-scroll" class = "same-height">
    some other content with vertical scroll, if it is higher than div#base-height
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .same-height {
      height: 100px;
      width: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #with-scroll {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8ph4qarL/